# How do I get my SQLite db to work in a fragment? I click to save data and it crashes

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

This is my Database Adapter; I cannot get it to run for some reason due to the problems with the "`this`" statements.

```
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    /**
     * Created by dpivl on 03/09/2015.
     */
    public class CowsDatabaseAdapter {

        CowDbHelper helper;

        public CowsDatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
            helper = new CowDbHelper(context);
        }

        public long insertData(String Loglength, String Logdiameter,String`enter code here`Logid) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(CowDbHelper.LOGLENGTH, Loglength);
            contentValues.put(CowDbHelper.LOGDIAMETER, Logdiameter);
            contentValues.put(CowDbHelper.LOGID, Logid);

            long id = db.insert(CowDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
            return id;

        }
        public String getAllData(){
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            String [] columns = {CowDbHelper.UID, CowDbHelper.LOGLENGTH, CowDbHelper.LOGDIAMETER, CowDbHelper.LOGID};
            Cursor cursor = db.query(CowDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                int cid = cursor.getInt(0);
                String Loglength = cursor.getString(1);
                String Logdiameter = cursor.getString(2);
                String Logid = cursor.getString(3);
                buffer.append(cid+ " " +Loglength+" " +Logdiameter+ " " +Logid+ "\n");
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }


        static class CowDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


            private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "logdatabase";
            private static final String TABLE_NAME = "LOGTABLE";
            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
            private static final String UID = "_id";
            private static final String LOGLENGTH = "Loglength";
            private static final String LOGDIAMETER = "Logdiameter";
            private static final String LOGID = "Logid";

            private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+LOGLENGTH+" VARCHAR(255), "+LOGDIAMETER+" VARCHAR(255), "+LOGID+" VARCHAR(255));";
            private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" +TABLE_NAME ;
            private Context context;







            public  CowDbHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                this.context=context;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

                try {
                    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Message.message(context, "" +e);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                try {
                    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
                    onCreate(db);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Message.message(context, "" +e);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

This is my `Message` Class:

```
    public class Message {
        public static void message(Context context, String message ) {
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

This is my `Fragment` which is the third fragment in my app. 
I have a viewpager and tabs.

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class Tab3 extends Fragment {

        EditText Loglength, Logdiameter, Logid;

        CowsDatabaseAdapter cowDbHelper;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_3, container, false);
            return v;

            Loglength = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.logLength);
            Logdiameter = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.logDiameter);
            Logid = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.logId);


            cowDbHelper = new CowsDatabaseAdapter(this);



        }

        public void saveData(View view) {
            String loglength = Loglength.getText().toString();
            String logdiameter = Logdiameter.getText().toString();
            String logid = Logid.getText().toString();





            long id = cowDbHelper.insertData(loglength, logdiameter, logid);
            if (id<0){
                Message.message(this, "Not Saved");

            }
            else {
                Message.message(this, "Saved Successful");
            }


        }
        public void viewCows (View view) {
            String data = cowDbHelper.getAllData();
            Message.message(this, data);
        }




    }
```

This is my logcat:

```
Error:(32, 23) error: constructor CowsDatabaseAdapter in class CowsDatabaseAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: Tab3
reason: actual argument Tab3 cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion
Error:(49, 20) error: method message in class Message cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,String
found: Tab3,String
reason: actual argument Tab3 cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion
Error:(53, 20) error: method message in class Message cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,String
found: Tab3,String
reason: actual argument Tab3 cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion
Error:(60, 16) error: method message in class Message cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,String
found: Tab3,String
reason: actual argument Tab3 cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:See complete output in console
Information:0 warnings
Information:5 errors
Information:Total time: 43.216 secs
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Stacktrace would help

Comment: I just posted my logcat, I hope you can help, thanks

Comment: cowDbHelper = new CowsDatabaseAdapter(this); In this line instead of 'this' can you try getActivity().getApplicationContext()?

Comment: that doesn´t work, it makesthis unreachable Loglength = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.logLength);

Comment: why you have return v; inside oncreateview. That makes your line unreachable

Comment: return v; should be at the end of the method onCreateView and use v.findviewbyid instead of getView().findviewbyid

Comment: i changed the edittexts and put them in onActivityCreated and I tried to use v.findviewbyid but it doesnt work at all. I also changed cowDbHelper = new CowsDatabaseAdapter(this);

Comment: to cowDbHelper = new CowsDatabaseAdapter(getActivity));

Comment: still no joy, there is a problem there with the Message class and the contexts, I have no idea how to fix it at this point